# In-report comments for other designers in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

What would be the best ways to comment/document a report in Crystal reports for other designers? I can think of the following ways:

- File > Summary Info...
- comments with `//` in Formulas
- Suppressed sections with information only for designers
- Comments in SQL commands

The more complex reports would be easier to read with this kind of commenting...

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. The only thing I'll add is that the Summary Info can usually be viewed by end users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the techniques you mention. I also place a text box in a suppressed report header section detailing key aspects of the report e.g. Title & Purpose, then a list of amendment history entries to include date, who made change, version number and change comments.
Lastly, if I need to comment the selection criteria (where comments disappear after saving), i create a formula called SelectionCriteria and copy the actual selection criteria into this formula.  I'll change the report selection formula to @SelectionCriteria and not only does everything work I can also add comments to the selection code.